# Unable to assign value to a var inside try in Scala

Tags: scala, try-catch, var

In my program, I have:

```
val f = Source.fromURL(url)
var lineList
try lineList = f.getLines.toList finally f.close()
```

I get compilation error:

> Error:(13, 1) '=' expected but ';' found.
>       try lineList = f.getLines.toList finally f.close()

What mistake am I making?In fact I am doing what error message asks me to do.

Comment: assign the var to something `var lineList = _`

Comment: when you declare a variable it should be explicitly initialized. Just initialize it like

var lineList = _

Comment: This gives  error:unbound placeholder parameter

Comment: Why not doing  `val lineList: Seq[String] = {
    try {
      f.getLines.toList
    } finally f.close()
  }` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not assigning something to lineList it needs a type definition, because the compiler cannot infer the type.

```
var lineList: List[String]
```

and if your not declaring an abstract class you need to assign it something, e.g. with the wildcard operator _

```
var lineList: List[String] = _
```

Comment: But doesn't this means we are creating a list object,even though we won't be using it as lineList would be assigned to a another object.

Comment: @Mandroid no you aren't creating any object, just declaring the variable.  You need to specify what type the variable should be.

Comment: In Scasti I had to assign it something. But that's probably due to how Scasti is set up.

Answer (score 0):

In scala, you cannot just name a variable like in java. Variable needs to be initialized.

If you want to create a variable without initialization you need to specify the type:

`var a = _` (doesn
t work)

`var a: Int = _` (works)

http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-2-learning-basics-scala-programming/scala-basic-tutorial-declare-variables-types/

It has a good explanation